# Docker Remote API returns 500 error on create container

Tags: python, rest, python-3.x, post, docker

I'm using the Python requests library to send docker commands to a remote server. I cannot get it to create a new container. Are there certain parameters (data field) that are required on the POST command. The server always returns a 500 error. My request look like this.

r1 = requests.post("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4243/containers/create?name=pycount")

I have tried with and without name, Hostname, a larger data field (from other examples).

The server always returns 500.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into the response body or your log files for an error message.

Comment: level=error msg="Handler for POST /containers/create returned error: EOF"